# Most performant way to write custom .on()/.bind() JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance, events, prototypal

I write lots of little libraries and modules and usually these libraries and modules have have some events associated with them. Until now I've been writing these like (shortened down a lot):

```
Library.prototype.on = function(event, callback){
  self = this;
  self.events[event] = callback;
}
```

then a user would do something such as:

```
Library.on('foo',function(){
  console.log('bar');
});
```

Is there a better more performant way to do this though or is this a standard way of implementing this? I want a simple API that i can drop into any JS project to support this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var EventEmitter = {
    constructor: function _constructor() {
        this._events = [];
        return this;
    },
    on: function _on(ev, handler) {
        if (!this._events[ev]) {
            this._events[ev] = [];
        }
        this._events[ev].push(handler);
    },
    removeListener: function _removeListener(ev, handler) {
        if (!this._events[ev]) return;
        this._events[ev].splice(this._events[ev].indexOf(handler), 1);
    },
    removeAll: function _removeAll(ev) {
        delete this._events[ev];
    },
    emit: function _emit(ev, data) {
        if (!this._events[ev]) return;
        this._events[ev].forEach(invokeHandler);

        function invokeHandler(handler) {
            handler(data);
        }
    }
};
```

I have a small `EventEmitter` I use when I need quick and dirty custom events.

The only difference between mine and your implementation is that mine allows multiple callbacks per event.

For anything serious I use an event library like [EventEmitter2](https://github.com/hij1nx/EventEmitter2)

Comment: Only weird thing is that removeListener only removes the last added. I think the intended use of `removeListener('event')` is probably how people use `unbind('event')` in jQuery where it removes all references (unless you add a namespace like `event.foo`)

Comment: @OscarGodson you have to remove all listeners manually. Calling `removeListener(ev)` will remove the last listener by sheer coincidence. (index is -1, so it removes the last item). You should call `removeListener(ev, handler)`.

Comment: I added a remove all option for easier teardowns that just sets this._events[ev] = []

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) for JavaScript.

[Spine](http://spinejs.com/) and [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone) have some nice implementations for observers.

But a new nice pattern is the Promises pattern that are documented at [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises)

[jQuery 1.7](http://jquery.com/) have implemented and is deeply using the promise pattern.

My favorite implementation from Promises pattern is the [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) from @kriskowal

I hope, that this sources help you in your quest.